# How to pass specific test data to test class by using junit5 parameterized test?

Tags: junit, junit5

Example: 
I am writing Junit5 test using parameterized test method,  I could able to run test using csvFileSource method,  the problem is my test class file contains several test 1. Login with correct credentials 2. Login with incorrect credentials and so on.

If i specify two set of credentials(one for login with correct credentials,one for login with incorrect credentials) at same csv file each test access  all the credentials and running two times. How to pick exactly the specific test data from csv file for each subtests in my test class?

Comment: You can just use two separate files and pick which one you want in `@CsvFileSource(resources=...)`, right?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp I could do that by separating files but I dont want to add new files for each and every test,  I would like to add all test data into one csv file. So I am stuck here from proceeding to write tests.

Comment: You can add an additional column or columns to the CSV file that define the expectations for the given line and then have a single parameterized test method that performs assertions based on the additional _expectation_ column(s).

Comment: Yes, i have tried that before and it is working but still i need to fetch all parameter from csv file in-order to run test and it results in fetching unwanted values. Currently i have a plan to keep different csv files for each tests to unblock from developing tests.

Comment: If someone is still looking for an answer for this question, this is an incorrect usage for CSV source. 

When you use a parameterized test using CSVFileSource, "all" records will be used to do a data driven test. The tests will run in parallel as well if we have defined the junit settings to run tests in parallel. 

If you still want to use a parameterized test with csv, then use CsvSource instead of CsvFileSource and define your csv as a part of test.

Reference here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-CsvSource

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional field into CSV file e.g. "Tag" and change you test execution depending on that field. e.g. in positive tests you check if Tag=positive.

Comment: yes, I have tried it but it is not working  because each test will fetch data from csv file and its fetching incorrect data,  if i try to add test data for different tests. Currently it is working if i add separate csv files for each test. May be i need to stick this for now in-order to proceed to write tests.